# Ros tutorial problem - roscd

Tags: ros, beginner-tutorials, roscd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I create a ros package, while I us roscd that cannot find it.

sunli@sunli-ThinkPad-T410:~/catkin_ws/src$ roscd begin_tutorials
roscd: No such package/stack 'begin_tutorials'

Then, I use rosws set,

sunli@sunli-ThinkPad-T410:~/catkin_ws/src$ rosws set beginner_tutorials
ERROR in config: Command requires a target workspace.

This problem often occurs and sometime I can fix it but I dont know what's the exact reason?

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78831/ros-tutorial-problem---roscd/) by [Kevin Li Sun](https://answers.ros.org/users/6651/kevin-li-sun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure your commands you listed are correct is the package called `beginner_tutorials` or `begin_tutorials`?

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0